# Is there a way to make qtimer wait until a function is done?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimer

I have an application in which I would like to do the following thing:

1. optimize a problem
2. wait for a certain amount of time, e.g. one minute
3. measure a certain property
4. repeat steps two and three several times
5. start again at 1.)

I want to start the entire process when clicking on a QPushButton. It is necessary that the step 2.) only starts when step 1.) is completely terminated. I dont know how long the optimzation process takes, therefre I cant just use QTimer.sleep().

I have solved this problem the following way:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys



class MyForm():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = QDialog()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.ui)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)
        self.waiting_interval = 10000
        self.ui.show()

    def start_timer(self):
        self.optimize()
        self.counter = 0
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.start(self.waiting_interval)



    def tick(self):


        self.timer = QTimer()
        if self.counter == 9:
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.start_timer)
        else:
            self.measure_property()
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.start(self.waiting_interval)
        self.counter += 1


    def optimize(self):
        pass


    def measure_property(self):
        pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=MyForm()
    app.exec_()
```

It produces the results that I want but I am looking for a smarter way to do this, maybe using signals and slots. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So far I see that you are using signals so assuming that the tasks optimize() and measure_property() take less than 10 ms is fine, optimize() and measure_property() take less than 10ms? if the task takes much longer, it must be executed in another thread since it can block the GUI

Comment: the tasks take much longer, measure() takes a few seconds and optimize() takes between 20s and 80s

Comment: then this task should not be done in the main thread, on the other hand does the result of optimize or measure_property show it somewhere in the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tasks that take a long time are heavy and tend to freeze the GUI giving a bad experience to the user, in these cases those tasks must be executed in another thread:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class ProcessThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.optimize()
            for _ in range(3):
                QtCore.QThread.sleep(60)
                self.measure_property()

    def optimize(self):
        print("optimize")

    def measure_property(self):
        print("measure_property")


class MyForm():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.thread = ProcessThread(self.ui)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.thread.start)
        self.waiting_interval = 10000
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.ui)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)
        self.ui.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=MyForm()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Still, there#s two things that I do not get. First of all, the thread never stops. Even when I close the gui, it still continues running. How can I stop it? And second, I do not get the structure. Why are you passing self.ui as argument in the constructor? And why does self.thread.tsart actually start the thread as defined in ProcessThread? You only created an instance of ProcesThread but you actually never call the method run on this instance?

Comment: @anonymous 1) In my test the thread ends when the GUI is closed, have you modified my test code? 2. I am making the GUI parent the thread just so that when the GUI is also destroyed the thread. If you realize the inheritance of QThread, therefore there are already defined behaviors that come from QThread (they have already done our work, that's the magic of the inheritance :-)) so you should not call run directly but when you call a start QThread creates a thread and invokes the run method.